# how to set language based on member id in boonex dolphin

Tags: boonex-dolphin

How to set a default language where user sign up.

EX: If first user choose Russian as his language while sign up(join form), then for every time after he login in the site should be in Russian language.

Like wise, if Second user choose English Language while sign up, then for every time after he login in the site should be in English language.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't change the language as per user logged id, the administrator who was set the default language, that language will be show in front end, otherwise not depends on user logged. If user need to change the language, the option is in home page, navigation menu.